# SQL Server 2012. Incrementing a integer based on the difference of row x+1 - row x

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario in sql server which I would really appreciate your help. I have 4 columns (ID to rownum) and 1 column (bindex) that I would like to calculate. These are detailed below

```
ID  StartDate           EndDate           rownum    bindex
A   27/06/2020 12:00    27/06/2020 16:48    1        1
A   27/06/2020 16:48    27/06/2020 21:36    2        1
A   02/07/2020 09:36    04/07/2020 09:36    3        2
A   06/07/2020 09:36    06/07/2020 21:36    4        3
A   06/07/2020 22:00    06/07/2020 23:58    5        3
A   07/07/2020 09:36    07/07/2020 21:36    6        3
A   08/07/2020 09:36    09/07/2020 09:36    7        3
A   11/07/2020 09:36    12/07/2020 09:36    8        4
```

What I am looking to do is increment the bindex variable by 1 where the startdate of row x+1 - enddate of row x is >=1. The first record would have a bindex value of 1 and then increment this by 1 for all the remaining rows until another break>=1 day is found.

Is there any easy way to do this in a cte or a simple looping structure that I've missed?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_enddate >= dateadd(day, -1, startdate) then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by rownum) as bindex
from (select t.*, lag(enddate) over (partition by id order by rownum) as prev_enddate
      from t
     ) t;
```